# Blank 1st page while converting from HTML to PDF using OpenOffice

Tags: c#, html, pdf, openoffice-writer

While converting HTML (the very basic HTML) to PDF, the output PDF always has 1st page blank. How to solve this?
Do I miss any specific properties?

```
xComponent = InitDocument(aLoader, PathConverter(inputFile), "_blank");           
SaveDocument(xComponent, inputFile, PathConverter(outputFile));

 private static void SaveDocument(XComponent xComponent, string sourceFile, string destinationFile)
        {
            var propertyValues = new PropertyValue[2];
            // Setting the flag for overwriting
            propertyValues[1] = new PropertyValue { Name = "Overwrite", Value = new Any(true) };
            //// Setting the filter name
            propertyValues[0] = new PropertyValue
            {
                Name = "FilterName",
                Value = new Any("writer_pdf_Export")
            };
            ((XStorable)xComponent).storeToURL(destinationFile, propertyValues);
        }
```

I tried to make workaround by deleting 1st page using PDFsharp, but after deleting, it shows me "The documents page tree has invalid node".

Comment: Main problem: empty 1st page. Secondary problem: error while deleting 1st page with PDFsharp. Since you do not include sample code and sample PDF relating to the secondary problem, I thought it was appropriate to remove the PDFsharp tag.

Comment: ok, I'll create separate question